# Android Studio: Help on createChooser

Tags: android, android-intent

Android Studio newbie here.
I have a project where when a button is pressed, it must ask the user where they would like the link to open: my phone's default browser or another application MyBrowser(where it will open the browser through MyBrowser). However, when I press the button, it automatically takes me to just my phone's default browser without giving the user the opportunity to choose.
Here is my code:

```
            openWeb = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.amazon.com"));
            Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("browser.school.mybrowser");

            Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(openWeb, "Please choose which browser...");
            if (openWeb != null) {
                startActivity(chooser);
            }
            if (launchIntent != null) {
                startActivity(launchIntent);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an intent filter to the activity to handle the request in the app manifest file. check [here](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/02/21/android-intents/)

Comment: Thank you! This was just what I was looking for.